# Stash variable as a parameter

Tags: stash

Is it possible to use a stash variable as a parameter further down the template.

```
{exp:stash:set name="logged_in_user"}{screen_name}{/exp:stash:set}


{exp:freeform:entries form_id="0" site_id="0" search:foo="{exp:stash:get name='logged_in_user'}"}

    {freeform:field:branch} <br/>{screen_name}

{/exp:freeform:entries}
```

Answer (score 1):

<del>Add the parameter parse="inward" to the Freeform tag and you should be good to go.</del>

It seems you can’t pass tags to the special search: parameter. Even parse="inward" doesn't work. [Here](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/stash/viewthread/13292#43305) you can find exactly how you can solve your issue.

Comment: Hi, that has no effect? Any ideas? cheers.

Comment: I added the correct solution to my answer. This time I tested it. ;)